# Strange behavior, writing a statement(declaration + initialising) into two different line does not work anymore

Tags: c#, wpf, inheritance, abstract-class, multiple-inheritance

I get a lof of syntax errors(missing simocolons...), when writing it like

```
 IGlobal[] all;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent(); 
            all = { new ATM(), new Bank()};
        }
```

Even this does not work:

```
IGlobal[] all;
all= { new ATM(), new Bank()};
```

But as soon as I write it in one line(for example in a method) it works:

```
IGlobal[] all= { new ATM(), new Bank()};
```

"IGlobal" inherits only from "IDisposable". "ATM" and "Bank" inherit from "IGlobal" and 1 custom abstract class.

What is the problem here, what can I do ?

Comment: Array Initializers only work when you declare the array.

Answer (score 0):

It is the syntax, where initializer and `new` is not exactly the same thing, and you cannot force it the way you want. All you can do is telling explicit array type

```
    all = new IGlobal[] { new ATM(), new Bank() };
```

Or this will work too, but I suggest NOT to use it unless you want to deliberately make your co-workers confused.

```
    all = new[] { (IGlobal) new ATM(), new Bank() };
```